# Changing the pattern and search size of trackers in Blender Python

Tags: python, tracking, movie-clip-editor

This may seem like a very simple questions but I cannot find/work out an answer that is consistent among all script. I need to change the pattern and search size of my motion trackers using Python. How exactly do I do this? I do not understand how the 2 identical commands such as

```
bpy.data.movieclips["MoveClip"].(null) = 15
```

could possibly be aware of whether the pattern or search size is to be changed, yet these are the commands that appear in the console when I change them via the GUI. I have scoured the internet and read many different documentations and examples yet am unable to find anything to help me.

Comment: i am still working on my answer but i found it is possible with changing .search_max and .search_min properties of existing markersexisting tracks (but they accept normalised coordinates vector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only change the pattern and search size when there are no tracks. Here is some sample code that changes the pattern size:

```py
clip = bpy.data.movieclips[0]
track = clip.tracking
settings = track.settings
settings.default_pattern_size = 17
settings.default_search_size = 42
```

Replace the first line with code that sets `clip` to whatever movie clip you want to change settings for.

As soon as you add a marker, the settings become read only.

See [`bpy.types.MovieClip`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.MovieClip.html) and [`bpy.types.MovieTrackingSettings`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.MovieTrackingTrack.html#bpy.types.MovieTrackingTrack) for more details.

Comment: this is really confusing, so cannot modify existing markers area and search, but in GUI it is still possible(although pop up info doesnt show python path as is the case with nearly all other GUI elements)